# for action is not working in for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to get these two “FOR Actions“ combined.Everyone separately is working without any errors but not in combination. 
The first one is just a simple loop and the second one is looking for some files. Is it possible to have them nested?

```
SET FILE[1]=*.CSV
SET FILE[2]=*.GPX  
SET FILE[3]=*.KMZ  
SET FILE[4]=*.TCX

ECHO Drag and Drop Folder here   
SET /P CHOICE=

FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,4) DO (  
    ECHO !FILE[%%G]!  
    PAUSE  
        FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%F IN ('DIR /B /S "%CHOICE%\%FILE[%%G]%" 2^>NUL') DO (  
        GOTO FILEFOUND  
    )  
)  
GOTO END

:FILEFOUND  
ECHO Min. 1 file found

:END
EXIT
```

Comment: Using `SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion`, apply the `!FILE[%%G]!` syntax pattern instead of `%FILE[%%G]%`

Comment: Wow that was fast and it’s working like a charm.
Shame on me – I used the FILE syntax for ECHO but not for the function itself ;-)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Using `SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion`, apply the `!FILE[%%G]!` syntax pattern instead of `%FILE[%%G]%` in all occurrence.

**Resources** (required reading from excellent http://ss64.com/ site):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)